# php 5.3 compilation failed using postgresq93-devel into Docker image

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, libpq

I am using a custom compilation based on PHP 5.3 and I need to upgrade the postgresql version from 9.2 to 9.3.

I am using docker for my infrastructure and the new lines I added was

```
yum remove postgresql -y && \
    rpm -i /tmp/postgresql93.rpm && \
    yum install postgresql93 postgresql93-devel -y && \ 
    rm -rf /tmp/postgresql93.rpm && \
```

The compilation failed and the message was:

```
checking for pg_config... not found
configure: error: Cannot find libpq-fe.h. Please specify correct PostgreSQL installation path
```

Then I added the postgresql-devel package into the upgrade lines

```
yum remove postgresql -y && \
    rpm -i /tmp/postgresql93.rpm && \
    yum install postgresql-devel postgresql93 postgresql93-devel -y && \ 
    rm -rf /tmp/postgresql93.rpm && \
```

I wonder why using the **postgresql-devel** is working if I also installed the **postgresql93-devel**.

In my previous compilation I was using **postgresql-devel** but I removed and I thought the **postgresql93-devel** should be work but it didn't.

Any idea why is this happening? What is the difference here and why do I need to use **postgresql-devel** either way?